# Direct proof from AC that every vector space has a basis?

Tags: vector-spaces, set-theory, alternative-proof, axiom-of-choice, hamel-basis

Let AC be the axiom of choice and VB be the proposition that every vector space has a basis. What's the "most direct" possible proof that AC$\implies$VB (in ZF)?

I know it's possible to prove Zorn's lemma (ZL) and then prove ZL$\implies$VB, and also to develop the theory of ordinals and then prove VB using transfinite induction. But, just out of curiosity, is there a more direct way?

I realize "more/most direct" is somewhat opinion based, but if you prefer, you could interpret my question as, "Can we prove AC$\implies$VB without ordinals and without explicitly mentioning (and without simply copying the argument of) ZL?"

Comment: The issue is that you can use the Axiom of Choice to build successively larger linearly independent sets, but I don't see how to prove that you must eventually exhaust the vector space of possibilities without using either Zorn's Lemma or transfinite induction.  Particularly if you're in a vector space of uncountable dimension.

Comment: Why do you want this? The most direct way, for me, would be to prove ZL from AC, and then VB from ZL.

Comment: @Vsotvep Just curiosity. And if there were a more direct route, it might be interesting / shed light on the connection between AC and VB.

Comment: I suppose an adaptation of the proof that $AC \implies WO$ (the latter being the fact that every set admits a well order) would be a bad flavor?  e.g. take a choice function $g$ which to every non-spanning set associates a vector not in the span, define a "nice" order on a subset of $V$ to be one such that every element is $g$ of the segment below it, and then the basis would be the union of all domains of nice orders...  (Of course, every "nice" order then turns out to be a well-order, so it doesn't quite avoid ordinals.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler Yes, especially if no other "more direct" route is possible. In that case, it would still be interesting to see the minimal amount of well-ordering/ordinal theory is necessary for VB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The axiom of choice by itself is useless. It just gives you a function. What can you do with it? Not that much, in most cases.

On the other hand, transfinite recursion is something that $\sf ZF$ itself can do pretty well already. And remember that the key point in transfinite recursion is that there is a function that tells you how to proceed to the $\alpha$ stage, assuming that you've done all the stages before $\alpha$.

Well, a choice function *is* a function. And it interfaces with transfinite recursion very well. Indeed, Zorn's Lemma and other similar equivalents were introduced to alleviate the need for transfinite recursion and induction. But any proof with Zorn's Lemma can be transformed into a proof using a choice function and transfinite recursion, including this one.

Fix a choice function from all the non-empty subsets of $V$. Now recursively add more and more vectors to your set, with the recursive rule being that if we have already gathered $\{v_i\mid i<\alpha\}$, then $v_\alpha$ is chosen to be any vector in $V\setminus\operatorname{span}(\{v_i\mid i<\alpha\})$. The only way we cannot make such choice is when what we gathered already is a basis; and so eventually the recursion must come to a halt, otherwise we are contradicting Hartogs' theorem, as it defines an injection from the class of ordinals into $V$, which is a set.

Now, we can, and should, also prove that this set of vectors is linearly independent. We can do that by induction; where we simply note that since $v_\alpha\notin\operatorname{span}(\{v_i\mid i<\alpha\})$, then it is not a linear combination of any finitely many $v_i$s for $i<\alpha$. Now, since the induction hypothesis is that those were already linearly independent, this completes the proof.

Comment: I have likened the axiom of choice to a knife, which is necessary when you're given a big steak, but is not enough on its own. You also need a fork. That fork is transfinite recursion.

Comment: Then Zorn's Lemma is like the restaurant serving you the steak in bite-sized pieces :)

Comment: With chopsticks. Or at least a napkin.

Comment: I don't know why, but transfinite recursion feels more intuitive to me than Zorn's lemma. In particular, I don't think I really understood ZL until I learned the way to prove it using transfinite recursion. (Which was basically yesterday.)

Comment: Of course, the proof of $AC \implies ZL$ or $AC \implies WO$ shows that in ZF, you can technically do more with AC than you'd think at first, using a choice function of "choose something that's left" to bootstrap into a well-ordering of a set or something similar.  That bootstrapping still feels to me like a trick or a hack (in the CS sense of the latter word), though.

Comment: @DanielSchepler: Yes, but that's not quite the case. If you omit Power Set from ZF, then AC is weaker than Zorn's Lemma or the Well Ordering Theorem.

Comment: @WillG: Yes, because we are used to recursive stuff from the finite proofs. But most people just have an innate phobia of the word "transfinite". Shame, really.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I wonder if you could look at an answer where I used transfinite recursion and tell me if I did it right. I really want to master transfinite induction. I think you are probably the expert on such things on this site. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3319791/570438